# C++ How to sort an array of arrays by one of the elements using comparator?

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool cmp(int x[], int y[]) {
    return x[0] < y[0];
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i][0] >> a[i][1];
    }
    sort(a, a + n, cmp);
}
```

This is a code I have created, but it does not compile. I don't know why...

Comment: `int a[n][2];` is invalid in `c++` so I would expect msvc to reject that.

Comment: What error does the compiler give?

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> a(n);`

Comment: I've replaced arrays with vectors and it compiles) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> it does not compile

- `std::sort` requires the elements to be move or copy assignable. You are trying to sort an array of arrays and you can't assign arrays to arrays. Example:

  ```cpp
  int foo[2]{};
  int bar[2]{};
  foo = bar;    // error
  ```

  Instead, put the array in a `class`. A single element of such a `class` *can* be assigned to, even though it contains an array. There's already a `class` for this in the standard library named [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).
- You are using a Variable Length Array, which is a non-standard extension. Use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to an create array-like container at runtime instead. `std::vector` is also in the standard library.

Here's how you could combine the two:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool cmp(const std::array<int, 2>& x, const std::array<int, 2>& y) {
    return x[0] < y[0];
}

int main() {
    int n;

    // check that reading `n` succeeds:
    if (!(std::cin >> n) || n < 1) return 1;

    // create a vector of `std::array`s with 2 elements in each:
    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> vec(n);

    // a range based for-loop to read the values from the user:
    for (std::array<int, 2>& arr : vec) {
        std::cin >> arr[0] >> arr[1];
    }

    // do the sorting:
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);

    // print the result:
    for (auto [a, b] : vec) std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
}
```